# Maya - Single Model with different animation

Tags: unity, maya

I am newbie in Maya and would like to clarify some implementations in Animation. I know how to create simple animations in Maya. These animations are exported to Unity3D (as `.fbx` with `controllers`) to use in my application.

I want to know whether it's possible to attach different animations to one model. For example, let's say, I have an arrow mark model and I want to show different animations for the model like moving left, moving right, moving up, moving down, etc. So that, when I export, I'll get one model - `Arrow.fbx` and different controllers - `LeftAnimController`, `RightAnimController`, etc.

Is that achievable? Or I need to create different Arrow mark model with it's own controllers.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible!

First, animation controllers are not imported, but created inside of Unity. They tell Unity which animation clip to play on the model. When you import an FBX file, you are importing one of three things:

1. Just a model
2. Just an animation
3. Both a model and an animation

You can choose what your FBX should include under 'Filetype Specific Options > Include' inside of Maya when you export. So it's possible to export one FBX file for the model, and then export other FBX files that just contain animations and put them together with an animation controller inside of Unity.

If you want it all in one FBX file, a common technique is to have each animation play one after the other in the timeline. For example, have your idle animation on frames 1-30 and your running animation on frames 31-70 and your shooting animation on frames 71-112, etc. When you import the FBX into Unity, you can split it into multiple animation clips based on frame #'s in the import settings.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'll take a try.
Thanks again.